# The definition of strong continuity via joint continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, semigroup-of-operators

A semigroup $S(t)$ on a Banach space $E$ is a family of bounded linear operators $\{S(t)\}_{t\ge 0}$ with the property that $S(t)S(s)=S(t+s)$ for any $s,t\ge 0$ and that $S(0)=I$. A semigroup is furthermore called
 *strongly continuous* if the map $(x,t)\mapsto S(t)x$ is continuous.
I was told that this is equivalent of saying $t\to S(t)x$ is continuous for every $x$.

How can I see the equivalence of two ways of defining strong continuity?
Could anyone expand what $(x,t)\mapsto S(t)x$ is continuous really mean? Can one show this via the usual strategy of 2-sided continuity? How could this be the same as saying  $t\to S(t)x$ is continuous for every $x$?

Appreciate for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusion let me give the two definitions of strong continuity different names, and from here on out I will not use the term *strongly continuous*.

1. A one-parameter semigroup $S(t)$ is called *time continuous* if for all $x \in E$ we have that $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \ni t \mapsto S(t)x \in E$ is continuous.
2. A one-parameter semigroup $S(t)$ is called *everywhere continuous* if $E \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \ni (x,t) \mapsto S(t)x \in E$ is continuous.

We see that time continuity follows immediately from everywhere continuity.
So, it seems that everywhere continuity is stronger in this sense.
However, we can proof that the continuity everywhere follows from the time continuity.

Pick an arbitrary $x \in E$ and $t>0$.
By the time continuity we can find a $\delta_1>0$ such that for all $|s-t|<\delta_1$ we have that $||S(s)x - S(t)x|| < \varepsilon/2$.
For any $y \in E$ we have, again by time continuity, that
$$ \sup_{|s-t| \leq \delta_1} ||S(s) y|| < \infty $$
Because we have bounded linear operators we can apply the uniform boundedness principle and get
$$ M := \sup_{|s-t| \leq \delta_1} ||S(s)|| < \infty $$
Now let $\delta_2 = \varepsilon / (2 M)$ and consider $||y -x || < \delta_2$.
We then have the chain inequalities
\begin{align}
||S(s)y - S(t)x||
&= ||S(s)y - S(s)x + S(s)x - S(t)x|| \\\\
&\leq ||S(s)y - S(s)x || + ||S(s)x - S(t)x|| \\\\
&\leq ||S(s)||\ ||y - x|| + ||S(s)x - S(t)x|| \\\\
&\leq \varepsilon / 2 + \varepsilon/2 \\\\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align}

It seems this is one of the special cases where separate continuity **does** imply joint continuity.

The same question and a shorter answer can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417011/is-t-x-mapsto-ttx-continuous-for-a-semigroup-of-operators-tt?rq=1)