# Is $(t,x)\mapsto T(t)x$ continuous for a semigroup of operators $T(t)$

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, banach-spaces, semigroup-of-operators

Is there a [strongly continuous one-parameter semigroup of operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup)  $(T(t))_{t\geq 0}$ such that the map $M:[0,\infty)\times X\to X$ defined by $M:(t,x)\mapsto T(t)x$ is not continuous? where $X$ is a Banach space.

I notice that such a map $M$ is continuous if the semigroup $T(t)$ is continuous in the operator norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't; the mapping $M$ is continuous for any strongly continuous one-parameter semigroup.

**Hint:** Fix $(t,x) \in [0,\infty) \times X$, then

$$|T(t)x-T(s)y| \leq |T(t)x-T(s)x| + |T(s)x-T(s)y| \leq  c |T(|t-s|)x-x| + c|x-y| $$

for any $y \in X$, $s \in [0,2t]$ where $$c := \sup_{r \in [0,2t]} \|T(r)\|<\infty.$$

Comment: This works thanks to the Banach Steinhaus Theorem right?

Comment: @user437713 Yes, that's correct.